# how pipe the 'get_url' of youtube-dl to ffmpeg stdin

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, youtube-dl

I'm not getting pass the output from the first process with Youtube-dl through pipe to stdin of ffmpeg. It is as if the Youtube-dl force the execution of process after pipe instead wait for his own result

`youtube-dl -f best -g [URL] -o pipe:1 | ffmpeg -ss 10 -i pipe:0 -vframes 1 capture.png`

get the return:

`pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: Can you please fill `[URL]` with a true URL?

Comment: @Rotem Yes, but still in the same problem

Comment: I asked you to update your post with true URL. But I don't think I know the answer anyway...

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
youtube-dl -f best [url] -o - | ffmpeg -ss 10 -i pipe: -vframes 1 capture.png
```

Comment: Yes, certainly works, but it seems to me that this method need to download the video at least until the second of '-ss'. If the second is 10 this process is fast, but if he is 1800 (30 min) it take too long. That's why i want to do this with url '-g'